# Who is 'functional' user?

Tags: discussion

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3425558/3102264) to the question [Compiler Error in C: expected ')' before '*' token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425547/compiler-error-in-c-expected-before-token) is linked to a user called 'functional'.

[image]

This user seems special because it is grayed out and contains neither reputation nor badges.

Is it a deleted user? Or an administrator user?

Comment: My guess is deleted user.

Comment: That user must have been deleted before SE began anonymizing deleted user names.

Comment: Interesting; the post history has an entry *Post Deleted by functional*, but no un-delete.

Comment: I wondered if it might possibly have been a migrated answer/question merged into that one, but I guess not since I can't see any revisions.

Comment: It's a functional user, meaning the user fulfills some "function"? I find it interesting that the answer is almost verbatim to the answer given by @MartinB. Is it perhaps a generated answer for a review queue?

Comment: I wonder if this is a case of someone who at some point, tried to "rage quit" and deleted all answers. Then the system/team restored the deleted items way back when before more actions were tracked in the revision history. IIRC, undeletes weren't added til later.

Comment: The OP earned a Famous Question badge because of this question.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: there were 4 answers posted almost simultaneously at 16:00; it was just a case of the answer being obvious to several people at once. In fact, functional's answer was post first by 23 seconds (also see the [timeline view](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3425547/timeline).

Comment: @Joe: 4 answers were posted within a minute of one another, with the first one about 90 seconds after the question was posted. These are not merged answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, Poops McGee! I thought I had done fingered it out. ESP then?? So, Mr. Harvey's got this one?